# Azure expressroute and VPN with Third Party NVA

Tags: azure, networking

I have a pair of FortiGate NVAs that will act as a termination point for IPSec VPN tunnels as well as serve as a backup connection for remote sites that are using expressroute.

The examples online from Microsoft show a similar solution but using the native VPN gateway. I need some help understanding how I can handle routing and failover when I am not using the native VPN gateway.

The parter is providing the expressroute as a spoke off of the existing MPLS network. Routes will be exchanged with Azure that way. I have never worked with expressroute before but I would assume that if the circuit fails or the remote site is unable to access the circuit, that specific route would be removed from the table in Azure via the eBGP relationship from the partner. I am not fully understanding how failover would occur.

A bit more about the architecture:

Two Vnets. One Vnet is the 'gateway' vnet. This would house all of the subnets for the FortiGate NVAs as well as a subnet for the expressroute object. There would be a single UDR for this Vnet. There would then be a second Vnet where shared services would live. This Vnet would be peered with the gateway Vnet. Access to the Internet would exit via the NVAs and remote site traffic would exit via the expressroute object. Where in this scenario would traffic be diverted if the expressroute failed? At the UDR?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have express route deployed in a VNET and you start advertising routes from On-Premises,then when see the effective routes of your NVA you can see On-Premises routes next hop as Express route MSEE IP.

When the circuit goes down, those routes will be revoked.

If you have VPN gateway and Express route which is a co-existence setup, where in Express route you are advertising the On-Prem route and with VPN you have declared the routes of On-Premises in Local Network Gateway, and if you see the effective routes in your NVA's NIC, you will have 2 routes to On-Premises, one with Express route and another with VPN. Express route will be the preferred route than VPN. And if Express route fails, the other route which is in place will be acting as a failover.

In your case, if express route fails, the route to On-Prem via Express route will be revoked and you need add a route to forward the traffic via the tunnel.Or else traffic gets dropped in your NVA.

Comment: Pretty much what I figured. Default route pointing to the NVA, more specific routes learned from the ER circuit. Learned routes removed, the default route is used. Does that sum it up correctly?